# Having trouble with select statements in a stored function

Tags: sql-server

What I'm trying to do here is execute `GetValue3` with `@ID` and get the `@results` that list @fullname, @phonenumber, @email, @city.

I'm getting 2 errors and I've been trying to figure out how to fix both.

Error #1

> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client

Error #2

> A select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval

What should I do?

```
Create Function GetValue3 (@ID INT)
returns nvarchar(350)
as
begin
    declare @results nvarchar(350)
    declare @fullname nvarchar(75)
    declare @phonenumber nvarchar(100)
    declare @email nvarchar(50)
    declare @city nvarchar(20)

    select -- this is where I get the first error.
        @fullname = p.Full_Name,
        @phonenumber = c.Phone, 
        @email = c.Email,
        @city = c.CityID,
        @results = @fullname, 
        @phonenumber, @email, @city -- this is where I get the 2nd error.
    from 
        d_People p, d_Contacts c
    where 
        c.PeopleID = p.PeopleID 
        and p.PeopleID = @ID;

    return @results 
end
```

Comment: mysql or SQL-Server(mssql)?

Comment: You miss the `;` after every `DECLARE` line

Comment: This is a SQL-Server database. I also added all the ";" at the end of the declares.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to below, I think it will give you what you're looking for:

```
create function GetValue3 (@ID int)
returns nvarchar(350)
as
begin
    declare @result nvarchar(350)

    select 
        @result = p.Full_Name + ',' + c.Phone + ',' + c.Email + ',' + c.CityID
    from d_People p
        , d_Contacts c
    where c.PeopleID = p.PeopleID
        and p.PeopleID = @ID;

    return @result
end
```

The reason you're getting errors is because in a `SELECT` statement you can **either** assign a value to variables **or** return data, you can't mix both together.

Also, the value of `@fullName` and `@phoneNumber` etc. is not being set separately at the top of the `SELECT` and then "moves down" so that at `@results = @fullname, @phonenumber, @email, @city` they are visible.

Comment: How would I go about returning more than 1 contact since I've got 1 person ID and many ContactID's?

Comment: @AlexanderHristov Then you would need a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) or a [table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: How would I go about transfering what I currently have to a table valued function?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code:

```
    Create Function GetValue3 (@ID INT)
    returns nvarchar(350)
    as
    begin
        declare @results nvarchar(350)
        declare @fullname nvarchar(75)
        declare @phonenumber nvarchar(100)
        declare @email nvarchar(50)
        declare @city nvarchar(20)

            select 

                @fullname = p.Full_Name,
                @phonenumber = c.Phone, 
                @email = c.Email,
                @city = c.CityID,
                @results = @fullname +','+ @phonenumber +','+ @email +','+ @city 
                from d_People p, d_Contacts c
                where c.PeopleID=p.PeopleID and p.PeopleID=@ID;

    return @results 
    end
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new and I didn't know I have to tell it +','+@nextparameter.

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as useful

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Function GetValue3 (@ID INT)
returns table
as
return select p.Full_Name, c.Phone, c.Email, c.CityID
              from d_People p, d_Contacts c
              where c.PeopleID=p.PeopleID and p.PeopleID=@ID;
```